# getting hidden elements in java using selenium giving error

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

when i select values hidden its showing error as:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:
>   Unable to locate element: {"method":"partial link
>   text","selector":"vehicle-make"}

Here is my code:

```
package section5.advWays.locatingObjects;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;   

public class CusXPathUsingAtt1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        WebDriver wd = new FirefoxDriver();
        wd.manage().window().maximize();
        Thread.sleep(5000);         wd.get("http://www.tirerack.com/content/tirerack/desktop/en/homepage.html");
        Select SelectMakedropdown = new Select(wd.findElement(By.id("vehicle-make")));      
        SelectMakedropdown.selectByVisibleText("BMW");
        Select YearSelectDropdown = new Select(wd.findElement(By.id("vehicle-year")));
        YearSelectDropdown.selectByVisibleText("2011");
        Select VehicleSelectDropdown = new Select(wd.findElement(By.id("vehicle-model")));
        VehicleSelectDropdown.selectByVisibleText("228i xDrive Coupe");
    }
    }
```

How to select those dropdown using selenium webdriver?

Comment: Did you try to use the `SelectMakedropdown.selectByValue("BMW")` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things:

1. I found that you first need to click on an element without which the Select menu won't open. So in my code, I'm first clicking on the element to enable select menu.
2. There are also some elements that aren't readily available. Say, for example the Year won't get enabled unless Make is entered.

Please see the code below:

```
WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.tirerack.com/content/tirerack/desktop/en/homepage.html");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Select Make')]")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Select Make')]")).click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("vehicle-make")));
Select SelectMakedropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("vehicle-make")));      
SelectMakedropdown.selectByVisibleText("BMW");

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Select Year')]")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Select Year')]")).click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("vehicle-year")));
Select YearSelectDropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("vehicle-year")));
YearSelectDropdown.selectByVisibleText("2011");

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Select Model')]")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Select Model')]")).click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("vehicle-model")));
Select VehicleSelectDropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("vehicle-model")));
VehicleSelectDropdown.selectByVisibleText("128i Cabriolet Base Model");

driver.quit();
```

UPDATE for Firefox:

I tried a lot, but I'm still unable to identify why isn't the selects working in Firefox. But I still managed to come up with a work around to do the needful. Here I'm using less use of clicks and more of features your application supports.

```
WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.tirerack.com/content/tirerack/desktop/en/homepage.html");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Select Make')]")));
WebElement we1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Select Make')]"));
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", we1);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("vehicle-make")));
WebElement SelectMakedropdown = driver.findElement(By.id("vehicle-make"));      
SelectMakedropdown.sendKeys("BMW");
SelectMakedropdown.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
Thread.sleep(1000);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Select Year')]")));
WebElement we2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Select Year')]"));
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", we2);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("vehicle-year")));
WebElement YearSelectDropdown = driver.findElement(By.id("vehicle-year"));
YearSelectDropdown.sendKeys("2011");
YearSelectDropdown.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
Thread.sleep(1000);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Select Model')]")));
WebElement we3 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Select Model')]"));
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", we3);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("vehicle-model")));
WebElement VehicleSelectDropdown = driver.findElement(By.id("vehicle-model"));
VehicleSelectDropdown.sendKeys("128i Cabriolet Base Model");
VehicleSelectDropdown.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

Comment: Prateek,Its not working getting Error as ElementNotVisibleError

Comment: Oh, that is strange :( It worked perfectly fine for me. Anyway, I have changed a few things. Please try now.

Comment: If possible copy and paste the exact code in your main and execute, also try once using Chrome. Lastly, if you're still getting error. Please let me know over which element you are getting the error (and if you noticed any different error this time).

Comment: Prateek ,these are my configurations : java1.8 , eclipse juno and FF36.0.4 version.

Comment: When you see it, visually does the Menu gets opened?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103716/discussion-between-khanam-and-prateek).

Comment: Prateek,Really u did a great job,its working fine, Thank You.

Comment: Thank you I'm glad that it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems page require to click on dropdown first , Try this code :

```
    wd.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='shopByVehicle-search-change']/div[1]/div[1]")).click();

     Select SelectMakedropdown = new Select(wd.findElement(By.id("vehicle-make")));     

     SelectMakedropdown.selectByVisibleText("BMW");
```

Above will run for sure.

Comment: Again giving error as :Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: ElementNotVisibleError: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated'ElementNotVisibleError: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated' when calling method: [wdIMouse::click]

Comment: Please go to that website then you will get to know the actual Issue.

Comment: Yes I tried in diff. way and got it working , please check updated answer.

Comment: Initially its clicking the first dropdown only and coming back to original position(resetting)not selecting the option BMW and throwing error in console.

Comment: @HelpingHands Could you please paste your whole code. Because I am also having the same issues as described by khanam. I tried testing using your code but the same error.

Comment: @Shah - I am using whole code given by khanam , I just replace part which find dropdown and select value , That part I posted as answer. You can try by putting some wait before find dropdown.

Comment: @HelpingHands Thanks for your reply but it is still not working according to your instructions. I am having the same error as khanam. My whole can be seen here [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4y80palkzn369oe/Capture.JPG?dl=0)