# How to open a URL in Selenium webdriver other than driver.get() and navigate()?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, driver

I'm using Selenium webdriver using Java and i know how to open a browser in 2 ways:

1. `driver.get("some url")`
2. `driver.navigate().GoToUrl("some url")`

Is there any option available to open a browser other than this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Java script, there is a command `window.location='url'` which can help you to achieve this.

```
String url = "https://www.google.com";
String script = "window.location = \'"+url+"\'";
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "Drivers\\IEDriverServer.exe");
WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(script);
```

**But again this is NOT a recommended method.**

Difference between `get()` and this command is that, get() would wait for your page to load but NOT Javascript, it would just do what you command and that's it. ***You would need to separately manage waits then***.

So if possible use the traditional methods. :)

Comment: can u please find the answer for this please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34064922/getting-hidden-elements-in-java-using-selenium-giving-error

Comment: I was talking about the question you added in comments. I tried to solve it and it's working for me. Let me know if it works for you too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34064922/getting-hidden-elements-in-java-using-selenium-giving-error